# URI routing Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, url-rewriting

Having problems with routing in CodeIgniter.

Here's my routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = "site/site/index/$1";
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['admin'] = 'admin/index';
```

I'm using modular system and my folder format is:

[image: folder]

In side the modules > site > controllers >site.php i have the following that gets the path of each that is entered into the cms, but the problem is when i navigate to localhost/my_site/ it shows the page but with errors, so if i put the following route in: $route['site/(:any)'] = 'site/site/index/$1'; it then works and shows all the pages but obviously I don't want this, i want it to know that the home page is set. Or can this be done via **htaccess DirectoryIndex** ??

If this doesn't make sense or you cant understand what i mean give me a shout and i'll try explain more details, but that's about it the problem.

Comment: the site.php in modules > site > controllers  is as follows:        http://pastebin.com/x5eAtb4d

Answer (score 1):

I think its because you default controller expects a parameter but you are not passing it one

```
$route['default_controller'] = "site/site/index/$1";
```

I think it should be

```
$route['default_controller'] = "site/site/index";
```

Comment: Yes I have that now but i want when first navigating to http://localhost/my_site i want the home page to show, instead I have to go to http://localhost/my_site/site/home which obviously i dont want, how can one get round this?

Comment: Try $route['default_controller'] = "site/home";  or $route['default_controller'] = "site/site/home";

Comment: but i dont have the function/method home its just one index method that gets the $path like so.public function index($path = ''){
  
     $page = $this->wc_main->getPagePath($path);
    
  $this->front->set('page', $page); 
  $this->front->set('title', ucfirst($page['title']));
  $this->front->buffer('content', 'site/index');
  $this->front->render();  
 }

Comment: then the wc_main model getPagePath is:     function getPagePath($path){
     $data = array();
     $this->db->where('path', $path);
     $this->db->where('status', '1');
        $this->db->order_by('pid', 'asc');
     $this->db->limit(1);
     $Q = $this->db->get('wc_pages');
     if ($Q->num_rows() > 0){
        $data = $Q->row_array();
     }

     $Q->free_result();    
     return $data;    
  }

Comment: Following on from that I managed to do it via:    $route['default_controller'] = "site/site/index/home"; so now navigating to localhost/my_site shows the home page.

Comment: Ah okay, sorry because you hadn't posted your code I was unsure how the controller was structured.  Glad you managed to sort it out though :)

Comment: Yes but thanks to your suggestions I wouldn't have thought of that! :)